# Solution for $A_{m,n}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}:n^{2}x^{3}+2020x^{2}+mx=0\}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $m$ and $n$ be non-zero integers. Define

$$A_{m,n}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:n^{2}x^{3}+2020x^{2}+mx=0\}$$

Then the number of pairs $(m,n)$ for which $A_{m,n}$ has exactly **two points** is?

**My Approach:**
A cubic equation can either have one real root or three real roots. Hence, it is impossible for any combination of $(m,n)$. Therefore, the required number of pairs is $0$. Is this the right way to solve it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It can have a repeated root, as in $(x-1)^2 (x-2)$

Comment: $x=0$ is always a solution...

Comment: @NN2 m cannot be 0 as it says m and n are non-zero integers in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution of $n^{2}x^{3}+2020x^{2}+mx=0$ is zero.

Since $m\neq 0,$ zero is not a root of the quadratic equation $$n^{2}x^{2}+2020x+m=0\quad \tag 1$$ The only possibility to fulfill the constraint is that $(1)$ has a double root. This is when the discriminant vanishes:

$$2020^2-4n^2m=0.$$
Thus we have $$m=\left(\frac{1010}{n}\right)^2  \tag 2$$ which is integer iff $n$ is a divisor of $1010.$
Because $1010=2\cdot 5 \cdot 101,$  the number $1010$ has $8$ positive (and 8 negative) divisors $$n\in \{\pm 1,\pm2,\pm5,\pm10,\pm101,\pm202,\pm505,\pm1010\}.$$
To each $n$ corresponds exactly one $m$ given by $(2).$ The number of convenient pairs is $16.$